# PHP Curl and Array

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I have problem with my codes. I am using curl for my project. All needed data are fetching correctly but there's a problem when the saving process started.

```
$SizeParag = sizeof($dr_match[0]);
for($CountParag=1;$CountParag<$SizeParag;$CountParag++) {
  $description = ($dr_match[0][$CountParag]);
}
```

I'm using this code to fetch all the paragraph but the problem is when I save the string `$description` it just only save the last paragraph.

How should I hold the value of all $description before saving it. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: `$description = array();$SizeParag = sizeof($dr_match[0]);
    for($CountParag=1;$CountParag<$SizeParag;$CountParag++){
    $description[] = ($dr_match[$CountParag][$CountParag]);
    }`

Comment: Thank you for your response. but when I tried the code it can only save the word Array.

Comment: sorry `$dr_match[$CountParag]`   not `$dr_match[$CountParag][$CountParag]` . Also it will be more good if you can show `echo "<pre/>";print_r($dr_match);`

Comment: Please show what value is there in `$dr_match` by using `echo "<pre/>";print_r($dr_match);` put that in your question

Comment: Notice:  Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\politicscurl.php on line (where the $description[] =($dr_match[$CountParag++); is written
It can only save only the word Array for the description.

Comment: Sorry. for more details please refer to my complete code here..  https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8yjc88430s47kf/SampleCurl.rar?dl=0  thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$description='';
$SizeParag = sizeof($dr_match[0]);
for($CountParag=1;$CountParag<$SizeParag;$CountParag++){
$description .= ($dr_match[0][$CountParag]) . ' ';
}
```

The .= appends the string instead of overwriting. Change ' ' to "\n" if you want each paragraph to be on a new line;

Comment: Still Not working for saving. It can only save the word array for $description.

Comment: //CHECKING IF RECORD EXIST
include("/connection.php");$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tblpolitics WHERE title='".$title."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){ echo "Link Already Exist";
}else{
 // Saving ALL CONTENTS OF THE LINK
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblpolitics (id, title, description)
     VALUES ('', '$title', '$description')";
     if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
         //echo "New record created successfully";
     } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);}}mysqli_close($conn);

Comment: user3378734...Thank you for you good. It works!. I just only misplace the code. Thank you for your knowledge and time.:-)

Comment: If you like my answer please select it as best answer :)